# Why can't I declare a reference to a mutable object? ("reference cannot be declared mutable")

Tags: c++, reference

Let's say we have a `test.cpp` as follows:

```
class A;

class B
{
    private:
        A mutable& _a;
};
```

Compilation:

```
$> gcc test.cpp
test.cpp:6:20: error: reference ‘_a’ cannot be declared ‘mutable’ [-fpermissive]
```

My gcc:

```
$> gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) 4.6.1
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Why?

Comment: Are you looking for a pointer?

Comment: Even if you could do this it would be useless because C++ does not contain any syntax that can change a reference. You can't even get the memory address of a reference. If you try you get the address of the object that the reference points to.

Comment: Sorry, I asked the wrong question. This is not a mutable reference, this is a reference to a mutable object! (I changed the title)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

There is no reason to have a reference member mutable. Why? Because const member functions *can* change the object which is referenced by a class member:

```
class B {
public:
    B(int var) : n(var) {};
    void Set(int val) const { n = val; }  //no error
    void SetMember(int val) const { m = val; }  //error assignment of member `B::m' in read-only structure
protected:
    int& n;
    int m;
};
```

Answer (score 13):

According to the standard:
[7.1.1 para 8]:

"The mutable specifier can be applied only to names of class data 
members (9.2) and cannot be applied to names declared const or static, 
and cannot be applied to reference members."

So it's just illegal.

Answer (score 12):

References can only be assigned when constructing an object, and cannot be modified thereafter. Thus making them `mutable` would have no meaning, which is why the standard disallows it.

Comment: But a reference can be const or non-const.  So `mutable A& a` should be ok, shouldn't it?  (Not near a compiler right now.)

Comment: But in this case, the `mutable` applies to the refered object, not the reference.

Answer (score 5):

This could blow your mind away, but a reference is never mutable (can't be made to refer to another object) and the referenced value is always mutable (unless you have a reference-to-const):

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
  int& i;
  A(int& n): i(n) {}
  void inc() const 
  {
    ++i;
  }
};

int main()
{
  int n = 0;
  const A a(n);
  a.inc();
  std::cout << n << '\n';
}
```

A const method means that a top-level const-qualifier gets added to the members. For a reference this does nothing (= `int & const a;`), for a pointer it makes the pointer, not the pointee const (= `int* const p`, not `const int* p;`).