# Do class member reference variables have in-built "const-correctness"?

Tags: c++, reference, const-correctness, class-members

```
struct A {
  int &r; 
  A (int &i) : r(i) {}
  void foo () const {
    r = 5;  // <--- ok
  }
};
```

The compiler doesn't generate any error at `r = 5;`.
Does it mean that `&r` is already *const-correct* being a reference (logical equivalent of `int* const`) ? [Here is one [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469209/why-cant-i-declare-a-reference-to-a-mutable-object-reference-cannot-be-decla) question.]

Comment: I'd since since const correctness applies to the `*this` and not the member, you have only modified the referenced object but not the reference itself. As you noted similar to the pointer case.

Comment: @Justin: Yep. That constructor should be A(int&i).

Comment: ... More like built-in const-incorrectness, but that depends on who you ask...

Comment: @iammilind: remember that as far as C++ is concerned, `const`-correctness is evaluated at the bit level, and cares not for semantics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "already const-correct", but:

Assigning to `r` is the same as assigning to whatever thing was passed into the constructor of `A`. You're not modifying anything in the instance of `A` when you do this, so the fact that `foo` is declared const isn't an obstacle. It's very much as if you'd done this:

```
struct A {
  int * r;
  A (int * i) : r(i) {}
  void foo () const { *r = 5; }
}
```

The fact that `foo` is const means that it doesn't modify anything in the `A` instance it's called on. There's no conflict between that and having it modify other data it was supplied with.

Of course if you happened to arrange for `r` to be a reference to some member of `A` then calling `foo` would modify the instance of `A` after all. The compiler can't catch all possible ways in which `const`ness of a member function might be violated; when you declare a member function `const` you're promising that it doesn't engage in any such subterfuge.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's the logical equivalent of `int* const`.

You may want to create and use appropriately qualified accessors in this case to prevent unwanted alterations to the value `r` references.

Answer (score 1):

I interpret a `const` member function as implicitly inserting `const` just to the left of every data member that doesn't already have such a qualifier. That `const` is already there implicitly for references (`int & const r;` is illegal syntax). In other words, references are "already *const-correct"* to use your nomenclature.

It would be nice if the `const` qualifier on a member function had the affect of inserting `const` in every possible valid position for every data member (e.g., data member `int ** foo;` acts like `int const * const * const foo;` in a `const` member function), but that isn't what happens, and it isn't what the standard says will happen.